# JQuery if statement is not running

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
    alert("clicked");
    if($('#result').html().length) {
           $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');
        } else { $('button[type="submit"]').removeAttr('disabled'); }
  });
```

The above code my if statement is not running. 
If I run the if statement in console it run fine but as soon as I nest it in the click function. the alert shows up but the my submit box is not greyed out.

Anyone know whats wrong with my code.

Comment: Is it wrapped with a `$(document).ready()`, what element is `#result`? Is the `alert()` executed?

Comment: Try using `prop` method:

     `$('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);`

Comment: if i run the code separately in console it works. But as soon as I nest the codes this part doesn't run $('button[type="submit"]').attr('disabled','disabled');

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle showing the problem?

Answer (score 1):

1. Make sure you wrapped your code in [`jQuery ready`](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)
2. If `$(selector)` doesn't match any DOM node it will return `undefined` when calling [`.html`](http://api.jquery.com/html/). Therefore remove the `.length`. (`undefined.length` -> throws an error)
3. Also change `.html` to `.text`. You can add `$.trim()` if you will remove whitespaces.
4. Use [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of [`attr`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) if you are using jQuery 1.6 or higher.

---

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function(){
        alert("clicked");
        if( $.trim($('#result').text()) ) {
            $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', true);
        }
        else { 
            $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

You can minimize your code to this:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $("input[type=checkbox]").click(function() {
        // Make sure myTest is an boolean:
        var myTest = Boolean( $.trim($('#result').text()) );
        // Send myTest as 2th argument:
        $('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', myTest);
    });
});
```

Comment: Could be taken a little further: `$('button[type="submit"]').prop('disabled', function(){ return Boolean($.trim($('#result').text())) ? true : false; });` (But I'd think that `!!$.trim(/*...*/)` would be about as reliable/easy.)

Comment: @DavidThomas I used `Boolean()` to not take focus off the main part of the script. I think that `!!` wouldn't be that clear for all.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
if($('#result').text()=='') $('button').prop('disable',true);
else $('button').prop('disable',false);
```